# How to start tomcat by Fabric with sudo as another user?

Tags: tomcat, fabric

My ubuntu server is login server by ssh key and user is ubuntu.
and tomcat user is tomcat and it's password is tomcat.
I want to start tomcat by Fabric.
and my method is like this, login in user is ubuntu, and want to su user tomcat;
but i had a error `su: must be run from a terminal`
if I remove the `pty=False`
it will run the `startup.sh` but will close after fabric finish.

```
suuser(user='tomcat',pwd='tomcat',command= '/data/tomcat/%s/bin/startup.sh '%port,pty=False)

def suuser(user,pwd,command='',pty=True):

    with settings(password= "%s" % pwd,
        sudo_prefix="su  %s -c " % user,
        sudo_prompt="Password:"):
        sudo(command,pty=pty)
```

Comment: remove pty=False and put & after startup.sh in command. suuser(user='tomcat',pwd='tomcat',command= '/data/tomcat/%s/bin/startup.sh &'%port)

Comment: remove pty=False and add & it's run the sh but tomcat didn't start ,

Comment: instead of suuser command use run("su - tomcat & /data/tomcat/{port}/bin/startup.sh") after setting up the env variables for login into the server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pty=False` add `set -m` to command, like this:

```
command= 'set -m; /data/tomcat/%s/bin/startup.sh '
```

`set -m` turns on job control, you can run processes in a separate process group.